# I want to update a INI file using awk

Tags: awk

I have an ini file which looks like this

```
[backup]
[persistence]
log_backup_timeout_s = 900
log_mode = normal
```

I want update this file to

```
[backup]
data_backup_parameter_file = /usr/sap/SI1/SYS/global/hdb/opt/hdbconfig/param
log_backup_parameter_file = /usr/sap/SI1/SYS/global/hdb/opt/hdbconfig/param
log_backup_using_backint = true

[persistence] 
basepath_logbackup = /usr/sap/SI2/HDB02/backup/log
basepath_databackup= /usr/sap/SI2/HDB02/backup/data
enable_auto_log_backup = yes
log_backup_timeout_s = 900
log_mode = normal
```

Comment: Can you just copy and paste the desired file from your question?  Do you need to make this change to lots of files on a host, or this file on lots of hosts?  What is your question here?

Comment: Don't use awk, use a real ini reader/writer, otherwise you're subjecting yourself to a lot of edge cases. As it is though, your question doesn't make much sense -- why not just overwrite the file if you want that?

Comment: Do you _need_ to use `awk`? Perl, for example, has an [INI reader/writer module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3a%3aIniFiles) that can make light work of this, and I'm sure Python will have one somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a perl version that uses the extremely simple `Config::Tiny` module.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use Config::Tiny;
use strict;

my $cfg = Config::Tiny->read( './backup.ini' );

# create a hash containing changes to [backup]
my %B = ('data_backup_parameter_file' => '/usr/sap/SI1/SYS/global/hdb/opt/hdbconfig/param',
         'log_backup_parameter_file' => '/usr/sap/SI1/SYS/global/hdb/opt/hdbconfig/param',
         'log_backup_using_backint' => 'true',
);

# loop through the hash and add them to the .ini stored in $cfg
foreach my $b (keys %B) {
   $cfg->{'backup'}->{$b} = $B{$b};
};

# create a hash containing changes to [persistence]
my %P = ('basepath_logbackup' => '/usr/sap/SI2/HDB02/backup/log',
         'basepath_databackup' => '/usr/sap/SI2/HDB02/backup/data',
         'enable_auto_log_backup' => 'yes',
);

# loop through the hash and add them to the .ini stored in $cfg
foreach my $p (keys %P) {
   $cfg->{'persistence'}->{$p} = $P{$p};
};


$cfg->write( 'new.ini' );
```

`Config::Tiny` is packaged for Debian (and derivatives), Fedora, Centos, OpenSuSE and other distros so is easily installed using the appropriate package management tools.  On other systems, install with CPAN.

There are numerous other perl modules for working with .ini files, some with more features, some that take a more object-oriented approach.  `Config::Tiny` just works with a hash and doesn't require as much setup or man-page reading as the more complex ones, so is good for a simple task like this.